# SQL distinct count from distinct rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, count, to-char

The following line of code gives me the time needed without duplicates, helping me avoid the actual dates.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(Start_Date_Time, 'HH:MI AM') AS StartTime
    FROM Section
    GROUP BY Start_Date_Time;
```

However, when I try to count the distinct course numbers in those specified times with the following code, the count adds duplicate start times in the rows.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(Start_Date_Time, 'HH:MI AM') AS StartTime, 
    COUNT(Course_No)
    FROM Section
    GROUP BY Start_Date_Time;
```

I do not want any duplicate start times. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(Start_Date_Time, 'HH:MI AM') AS StartTime, COUNT(Course_No)
FROM Section
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(Start_Date_Time, 'HH:MI AM');
```

In your first query, the `GROUP BY` isn't really doing much.  It is producing one row for each date/time combination.  The `select distinct` is then reducing the number of rows.  You would get the same result without the `group by`.

Comment: Thank you for this. I did not know you could use a group by statement like that.